# Server Error in '/' Application :(

Tags: asp.net

i uploaded my website to my web host server.

the website was running good in my local computer but on the server it's showing me this error :

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The file '/MasterPage.master' does not exist.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:   <%@ page title="" language="VB" masterpagefile="~/MasterPage.master" autoeventwireup="false" inherits="news, App_Web_giiaopeh" %>
>   Line 2:
>   Line 3:   <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" >
>
> Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
>
> Source File: /news/news.aspx      Line: 1
>
> ---
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4200; ASP.NET
>   Version:2.0.50727.4016

can you help me please?

the master page already in the server but i can't understand from where did this code came from `inherits="news, App_Web_giiaopeh"; %>`

because my original code is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="news.aspx.vb" Inherits="news" %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File `MasterPage.master` doesn't exist in the root of your web site. Forgot to upload it too?

`Source File: /news/news.aspx Line: 1` means that `new.aspx` is under `/news` folder but `~/MasterPage.master` means root directory.

So Move `MasterPage.maste` from `/news` to root or remove `~/`

Comment: Thanks A lot, now this problem has been resolved but there is another problem I'll Ask about it separately :]

Answer (score 0):

Note that it has also dropped `CodeFile="news.aspx.vb"` from the `<%@Page%>` statement. `App_Web_giiaopeh` will be the name of the temporary assembly that it has compiled `news.aspx.vb` into.

Answer (score 0):

Is the directory where `MasterPage.master` set up as an application root in IIS?

I'm guessing the issue appears because `~/` doesn't correctly reference the root of your application.

Comment: Thanks A lot, now this problem has been resolved but there is another problem I'll Ask about it separately :]